# If I plug my ipod to another computer's itunes, my musics will be deleted?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, ipod

I'm thinking about use Ubuntu's Rythmbox to synchronize music, but I need the iTunes from my windows to get some apps.

If I plug my ipod to a windows with no musics on it (to get my apps), my musics will be deleted from ipod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm what Nathan G. reported. I have a computer with Windows, and when I plug my iPod on that computer, it says me it is already synchronized with an iTune library; it asks me if I want to synchronize it with the library present on Windows, warning me that the content of the iPod will be deleted, if I decide to do so.

I didn't select *Manually Manage Music* in both the computers.

Comment: From the Rythmbox dev mail archive: [Manually Manage Music should work.](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/rhythmbox-devel/2010-June/msg00042.html)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it asks you. You can say no. However, I'm not sure if this requires Manually Manage Music to be checked in the Summary tab.

As always, make a good backup just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Go into the Preferences of iTunes.  Under the Devices tab, there is a checkbox for "Prevent iPods and iPhones from syncing automatically".  Make sure that option is checked and you are in the clear.